# Understaning of static objects in main function

Tags: c++, qt, oop, static

I am trying to build application, where it will be choosen according to console argument if its gonna be gui application or console.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QCommandLineParser parser;
    parser.setApplicationDescription("Test");
    parser.addHelpOption();
    parser.addVersionOption();
    QCommandLineOption guiOption(QStringList() << "g" << "gui", "Gui");
    parser.addOption(guiOption);
    parser.process(app);

    bool isGUI = parser.isSet(guiOption);

    APPstub stub(0,isGUI);


if (isGUI) {                //GUI APP
    static APP_Window ui(&stub);   ////*****THIS
    ui.show();
}
else {                      // CONSOLE APP
    static APP_Console con(&stub);  ////*****THIS
    con.showMenu(); 
    }

    return app.exec();
}
```

I figured out that I need those objects created in condition(////*****THIS)
needs to be static, but I dont understand why? 
The thing is: when I had for example APP_Window ui(&stub) outside of the condition, it worked and showed gui.
If I have it inside the condition, Window pops and go away quickly.

I am confused about that... could you help me understand that problem? 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not declared static the APP_Window object is local to the { } block in which it's declared. Once outside of the block, the object is deallocated. Any local object is allocated on the stack which gets automatically freed by the compiler once we reach the end of the block.

An object declared static within a {} block (or function) is really a global object with local visibility. Therefore, it is persistent until the application exits.

For instance, these are local variables only visible and valid in the block in which they are defined:

```
{
    int i = 3;
    ...
}
```

or

```
void f() {
    int x = 5232;
}
```

Now these variables are global although they only have a local scope (in the block in which they are declared):

```
{
    static int i = 3;
    ...
}
```

or

```
void f() {
    static int x = 5232;
}
```

Comment: thank all of you, would also do thumb up but not enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

Because when your code goes out of braces:"con" and "ui" objects will be destroyed because their scope limited by braces if they are not static.

Comment: thank all of you, would also do thumb up but not enough rep

Answer (score 0):

Making them `static` extends the lifetime of the object that's created until the end of the program.

When you don't have them `static`, the lifetime ends at the end of the scope where the variable is defined.

Comment: thank all of you, would also do thumb up but not enough rep

Answer (score 0):

If the objects are not `static` they will cease to exist at the end of their containing block (at the closing `}`) and their destructors will be invoked.

Presumably the objects are registered in some way so they are used within the call of `app.exec()`.   Their destructors would then deregister them, so the cannot be used.

Comment: thank all of you, would also do thumb up but not enough rep